# How to extract a string of unknown length between two delimiters in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I have a data frame containing a column with user's email addresses. The format of the email address could be anything. I need to create a new column called 'agency' with just the domain of the user's email (in other words, extract the value between '@' and the last '.').

Example:

- 'user1@mydomain.com' becomes 'mydomain'
- 'u2.surname@yourdomain.ca' becomes 'yourdomain'

I don't seem to be able to tackle the syntax to get there...

So far the best I could do was to eliminate the part before @:

```
Azure_table <- Azure_table %>%
                  mutate(
                    agency = gsub(".*@", "", userPrincipalName)
                  )
```

Which gives me the following result:
[image: output]

How do I eliminate the text after the last dot (.com, .ca, etc)? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following along with `str_extract` should suit your needs. Instead of replacing text with an empty string, I just extracted the desired information.

```
pattern = "(?<=@).*(?=\\.[a-zA-Z]+$)"
```

Test cases:

```
s1 <- "example.ex@subtel.com"
s2 <- "example.ex@subtel.eu"
s3 = "example@hello.something.com"
s4 <- "example@example.applestore.apple.com"


str_extract(s1, pattern)
[1] "subtel"
str_extract(s2, pattern)
[1] "subtel"
str_extract(s3, pattern)
[1] "hello.something"
str_extract(s4, pattern)
[1] "example.applestore.apple"
```